# How do I restrict Bluetooth before logging in or when locked?

Tags: security, bluetooth

I'd like my computer's Bluetooth to be disabled before logging in. My Android phone keeps itself unlocked if connected to my computer's Bluetooth, so if someone turns on my computer, they could unlock my phone and I'd like to prevent this.

How can I achieve this on Windows 8.1 64 bit?

Comment: What OS/version?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'm using Windows 8.1 64 bit, thanks.